# jquery - Buttons resize fixed divs in fixed percentage web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, button

I've been fighting with this for a few hours now (I'm a bit new to js) and I decided to put it up to the community. I have this web app I'm building that is all based on percentages of screen sizes. The divs are fixed position, contents absolute within those divs. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MycF6/31/   and the code I'm working with:

```
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
    $("#socialDash")
        .click(function () {
        $("#socialStream")
            .hide("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, "1000");
    });
});

$("#socialDash")
    .click(function () {
    $("#workBench")
        .effect("scale", {
        percent: 178,
        origin: ['middle', 'right'],
        direction: 'horizontal'
    }, 700);
});

$("#niner")
    .click(function () {
    $("#socialStream")
        .show("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, "1000");
    $("#workBench")
        .effect("scale", {
        percent: 56,
        origin: ['middle', 'right'],
        direction: 'horizontal'
    }, 500);
});

$(".socialButton")
    .click(function () {
    $("socialButton")
        .removeClass(".clicked");
    $(this)
        .addClass(".clicked");
});
```

I want it so when I click the top button on the left (1) the left div of the inside content slides left and the div on the right expands to take its place. For the other two buttons (2),(3), I want the divs in original proportion. The other issue is when buttons (imgs) are clicked they have background that remains persistent instead of swapping to the next clicked button as I have tried to identify in that last bit of code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: People may disagree with this statement, but in general, I find that designing with absolute positioning in mind from the start is a recipe for headaches down the road. Absolute position should be used as a last resort, if not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution (basically I rewrote everything). It isn't pretty, but it works. Here is the new jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MycF6/42/ if you are interested.

And the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dash").click(function () {
        $("#stream").animate({
            width: "0"
        }, "fast").hide("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, "fast");
        $("#dash").addClass("clicked");
        $("#fb").removeClass("clicked");
        $("#twit").removeClass("clicked");
        $("#work").animate({
            width: "100%"
        }, "slow");
    });
    $("#twit").click(function () {
        $("#work").animate({
            width: "59%"
        }, "fast");
        $("#twit").addClass("clicked");
        $("#dash").removeClass("clicked");
        $("#fb").removeClass("clicked");
        $("#stream").animate({
            width: "40%"
        }, "fast").show("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, "slow");
    });
    $("#fb").click(function () {
        $("#work").animate({
            width: "59%"
        }, "fast");
        $("#twit").removeClass("clicked");
        $("#dash").removeClass("clicked");
        $("#fb").addClass("clicked");
        $("#stream").animate({
            width: "40%"
        }, "fast").show("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```